# Getting data from database but not post and update

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

**This is the error occurs in web console:**

```
vendor.bundle.base.js:2 POST http://localhost/dashboard_new/public/addPackage 404 (Not Found)
send @ vendor.bundle.base.js:2
ajax @ vendor.bundle.base.js:2
addPackage @ all_package_listing_view:522
onclick @ all_package_listing_view:361
all_package_listing_view:546 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'errors')
    at Object.error (all_package_listing_view:546)
    at c (vendor.bundle.base.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (vendor.bundle.base.js:2)
    at l (vendor.bundle.base.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (vendor.bundle.base.js:2)
```

> recently I have solved datatables error using "Yajra datatable", but
> after that, I can retrieve data after updating it from PHPMyAdmin it
> shows on the web for but I couldn't update or add. I have used PHP,
> ajax, and js...

```
  function addPackage()
        {
          console.log('here');
            // e.preventDefault();
            var formData  = new FormData(jQuery('#addform')[0]);

            $.ajax({
                url:"http://localhost/dashboard_new/public/addPackage",
                type:"POST",
                data:formData,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success:function(dataBack)
                {
                  console.log(dataBack);

                    $('#form_submit_success').modal('show');
                    setTimeout(function() {$('#form_submit_success').modal('hide');}, 2000);

                    $("#addform").trigger("reset");

                   window.location.href = '<?php echo url('/');?>'+"/all_package_listing_view";




                }, error: function (xhr, status, error)
                {

                    // console.log(xhr.responseJSON.errors);
                    $.each(xhr.responseJSON.errors,function(key,item)
                    {

                        $('#form_submit_error').modal('show');
                        setTimeout(function() {$('#form_submit_error').modal('hide');}, 2000);
                    })
                }

          });

        }


  $(document).on("click",".edit",function()
        {

             var id = $(this).attr("id");
            console.log(id);
            $.ajax({
                type:"get",
                url:"http://localhost/dashboard_new/public/edit_pack/"+id,
                // data:{id:id},
                success:function(data)
                {
                 console.log(data);
                    $("#id").val(data[0].id);
                    $("#aname").val(data[0].name);
                    $("#adetails").val(data[0].details);
                    $("status").val(data[0].status);
                    $("#aamount").val(data[0].amount);


                }

            })
        })


           function updatePackage()
       {

            var formData  = new FormData(jQuery('#editform')[0]);
            var idRow = $("id").val();
            console.log(formData);
            $.ajax({
                url:"{{route('updatepackage')}}",
                type:"POST",
                data:formData,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success:function(dataBack)
                {
                    $("#signupForm").html("<li class='alert alert-success text-center p-1'> Edited Success </li>");
                    $("#"+idRow).html('')
                    $("#"+idRow).html(dataBack)
                    window.location.href = '<?php echo url('/');?>'+"/all_package_listing_view";

                }, error: function (xhr, status, error)
                {

                    // console.log(xhr.responseJSON.errors);
                    $.each(xhr.responseJSON.errors,function(key,item)
                    {

                        $("#errorUpdate").html("<li class='alert alert-danger text-center p-1'>"+ item +" </li>");
                    })
                }
            })


      }



              function deletePackage(id)
        {

            // var id = $(this).attr("id");
            // console.log(id);
            $.ajax({
                type:"get",
                url:"http://localhost/dashboard_new/public/deletepackage/"+id,
                success:function(data)
                {
                    console.log(data);
                    alert(data.success);
                    // $("#"+data.id).remove();
                window.location = "http://localhost/dashboard_new/public/all_package_listing_view";

                }


            })
        }
```

There is the screenshot of error:
[image]

Comment: It complaints that it can't find the URL you're trying to post the data to. Make sure that URL is correct. Looking at the screenshot, you're using `localhost:8000` but the link only has `localhost` (with out the custom port). Also, should `/dashboard_new/public` really be in the URL and do you have an endpoint named `addPackage` (since the other endpoints seem to be `snake_case`)?